# Display message if no posts in Custom Post Type loop

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags

I am trying to get this thing to work, but can't figure out where is the problem. I added else statement, but it does not work. I was able to get this work with jQuery, but I need it to work in PHP as I will need to show this message in different languages. Can somebody help me?

Here is the code I have now:

```
        <?php

        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom_jobs', 'posts_per_page' => 30, 'order' => 'ASC' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $loop ):
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        ?>

        <div class="accordion-container" id="accordion-container">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionJobs<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-parent="#accordionJobs<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                        <div class="card-body"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>  

        <?php else : ?>

            <h1>There are no posts!</h1>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're only checking `if ( $loop ) {`.

`$loop` isn't empty, it's a full `WP_Query` object with all the information about the query in it, even if no posts were returned. To check if the query actually returned any posts you need to use `$loop->have_posts();`:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ):
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    endwhile;
else:

endif;
```

Comment: You are a star! This worked, thanks a lot!